# Update fragment after change in adapter for RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I'm trying to update the `RecyclerView` on  my fragment when the user holds in the `itemview` and it deletes the object from the database.

I've seen numerous answers and tried some implementations of them to no success. I've tried `notify()` methods. Im not sure how to approach this anymore and not sure if its possible the way I'm trying to do. The object does delete and when the fragment reloads the item is gone. Could someone help out please?

This is the adapter:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
    final OfflineModule model = assList.get(position);
    holder.textView_name.setText(model.getCode());
    holder.textView_bio.setText(model.getDesc());
    holder.txtIDMod.setText(model.getId());        
    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener((View v) ->{
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setMessage("Delete " + model.getCode() + "?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        RealmHelper helper;
                        Realm realm;
                        // initialize realm
                        Realm.init(mContext);
                        //SETUP REEALM
                        RealmConfiguration defaultConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                                .schemaVersion(0)
                                .build();
                        realm=Realm.getInstance(defaultConfig);
                        helper = new RealmHelper(realm);
                        List<FAssessment> assessmentList =helper.retrieveAF(model.getId());
                        assert assessmentList != null;
                        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                            @Override
                            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                                for(FAssessment a : assessmentList) {
                                    a.deleteFromRealm();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        OfflineModule result = realm.where(OfflineModule.class)
                                .equalTo("code", model.getCode()).findFirst();
                        assert result != null;
                        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                            @Override
                            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                                result.deleteFromRealm();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    }
                });
        builder.create();
        builder.show();
        return true;
    });

}
```

And the activity:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_update,
            container,
            false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    RelativeLayout = contentuserimportMod;
    RelativeLayout1 = delResMod;
    moduleID = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
    moduleCode =Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getIntent().getStringExtra("code");
    moduleName =Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getIntent().getStringExtra("desc");
    Realm.init(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()));
    RealmConfiguration defaultConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .schemaVersion(0)
            .build();

    realm=Realm.getInstance(defaultConfig);
    helper = new RealmHelper(realm);
    init();
    getAssessList();
    return view;
}
private void init(){
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    AssList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    textView1.setText("Assessments - "+moduleName);
    List<AssessmentType> list = helper.retrieveAT();
    List<String> listString = new ArrayList<>();
    for(AssessmentType a : list) {
        listString.add(a.getDesc());
    }
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listString);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerOffline.setAdapter(adapter);
}
private void getAssessList(){
    RealmHelper helper=new RealmHelper(realm);
    FAssessmentList =helper.retrieveAF(moduleID);
    AssessTabUpdateAdapter adapter = new AssessTabUpdateAdapter(getContext(), FAssessmentList);
    AssList.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    AssList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

I would like the delete to show immediately or just call like a reload on the fragment when the delete happens just so that it removes the deleted item from the view.

Comment: First of all why do you do "delete" operation inside onClick? Make it a separate function and just call it, you have to remove it from assList and then call the notifyItemRemoved method.

Comment: Hi @Erbex.. When you call the "notifyDateSetChanged" method? You need to call it everytime you modify you data in the list. Calling it you tell adapter to "see itself" and update the data contained.

Comment: have you tried implementing interface.you have to define interface in Adapter after delete you have to call this interface  to update the result in fragment and make sure you implement the interface in fragment